# In-app purchase with multiple user accounts

Tags: android

I'm currently experimenting with Google in-app purchase.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases

> The Google Play service returns only the purchases made by the user
>   account that is currently logged in to the device.

Under my Settings -> Accounts -> Google, I had more than 1 accounts. So, how can I know which account Google Play Service will referring to?

Is it possible that I can retrieve in-app purchase status for all available accounts in the device? As I would like to unlock the feature to all users of the same device, as long as there is at least 1 "paid user" in the device.